# How to dump clustering results in MOA

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, data-stream, moa

Please let me know after using data stream clustering algorithm from MOA like Clustream, how can I dump the clustering Result into csv file, which shows each row of arff data file belong to finally which cluster??

I tried the export CSV option in the framework but it gives a file with the calculated evaluation metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to resort to writing your own code. Luckily, you don't have to do that in Java/Maven (which would require compilation), as you can either use MOA from within [Jupyter Notebooks](https://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-with-moa/) or the scripting tab in MOA's user interface itself.